# Response data not getting isotope position

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a text box when I submit the data, the page will not refresh and showing that data in a box. But my issue is, box is not showing in correct position. Please find the image,[image]                  It will give you a brief idea.  I am using isotope js.

After refreshing the page all the data box position is showing properly that means isotope position is getting correctly after refresh. But without refresh, response data is not getting isotope position. Please check firebug result.

**Firebug**

```
<div class="card col2 padding-20 showbox" data-social="item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 200px;">
<div id="innerbox_1" class="card share col1" data-social="item" style="display: block;">
<div class="card share col1" data-social="item" style="position: absolute; left: 640px; top: 200px;">
<div class="card share col1" data-social="item" style="position: absolute; left: 960px; top: 200px;">
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Please check the  code given below. If you have any doubt in code please let me know.

HTML

```
<div class="day" data-social="day">
<!-- START ITEM -->
<div class="card col2 padding-20 showbox" data-social="item">
<form id="form-for-freetext" class="simform no-margin" data-social="status" autocomplete="off" action="post">
    <div class="status-form-inner">
     <ol class="questions">
     <li class="current">
     <span>
     <label for="status-q1">{{ trans('social/socialPage.customerHistoryLabel') }}</label>
     </span>
     <span class="successMessage"></span>
     <input id="freetext" type="text" name="freetext" class="freetext">
     <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $customerdetails->customer_id;?>">
     </li>
     </ol>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
    <div class="controls">
    <div class="progress" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </form>
</div>
<!-- END ITEM -->
 <!-- START ITEM -->
 <div class="card share  col1" data-social="item">
 <div class="card-header ">
 <h5 class="text-complete pull-left fs-12">News <i class="fa fa-circle text-complete fs-11"></i></h5>
 <div class="pull-right small hint-text">5,345 <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="card-description">
 <h3>Ebola outbreak: Clinical drug trials to start next month as death toll mounts</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="card-footer clearfix">
 <div class="pull-left">via <span class="text-complete">CNN</span>
 </div>
 <div class="pull-right hint-text">Apr 23</div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div></div>
 </div>
<!-- END ITEM -->
</div>
 <!-- END DAY -->
```

**JS for insert data and getting last result**

```
var generateID = 1;
$('#form-for-freetext').on('keypress', function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".progress").css( "width", "0%" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", 0);
        $(".progress").show();
        var freetext       = $('#freetext').val();
        var id             = $(":hidden", this).val();
        var token          = $('input[name=_token]').val();
        var dataString     = 'freetext='+freetext+'&id='+id+'&token='+token;
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "{!! URL::to('socialfreetext') !!}",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                // Progress bar begin
                var stops = [0, 50, 100];
                $.each(stops, function(index, value){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".progress").css( "width", value + "%" ).attr('aria-valuenow', value );
                    }, index * 100);
                    $(".progress").css( "width", value + "%" ).attr('aria-valuenow', value ).fadeOut(5000);
                });

                // Progress bar end

                // Response data begin
                var date           = data.responsecusthistory.created_at.split(" ")[0];
                $(".showbox").after('<div class="card share col1" data-social="item" id="innerbox_'+generateID+'"><div class="circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Label" data-container="body"></div><div class="card-header clearfix"><div class="user-pic"><img alt="Profile Image" width="33" height="33" data-src-retina="/assets/img/profiles/avatar.jpg" data-src="/assets/img/profiles/avatar.jpg" src="/assets/img/profiles/avatar.jpg"></div><h5 style="margin-top:0;"><?php echo $customerdetails->firstname ." ". $customerdetails->lastname; ?></h5><h6><span class="location semi-bold"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <?php echo $customerdetails->street .",". $customerdetails->city; ?></span></h6></div><div class="card-description"><p>'+data.responsecusthistory.freetext+'</p><div class="via">via Twitter</div></div><div class="card-footer clearfix" style="border-top: 1px solid #e1f0fd;"><div class="time">'+date+'</div><ul class="reactions"><li><a href="#">5,345 <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></a></li><li><a href="#">23K <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a></li></ul></div></div>');
                //$('.innerbox').css('display', 'inline');
                //$('.innerbox').show("slow");
                //$('.innerbox').css('display', 'inline');
                $("#innerbox_"+generateID).hide().fadeIn(2000);
                generateID++;
                // Response data end

            },
            error: function(data) {
                if( data.status === 422 ) {
                    //process validation errors here.
                    var errors = data.responseJSON;
                    errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
                    $.each( errors , function( key, value ) {
                        errorsHtml += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>';
                    });
                    errorsHtml += '</ul></div>';
                    $( '.error-message' ).html( errorsHtml );
                }
            }
        });
        $('#freetext').val('');
        return false;
    }
    //window.setTimeout(function() { $(".progress").alert('close'); }, 100);
});
```

**JS for Isotope is**

```
/* ============================================================
 * Pages Social
 * ============================================================ */
<script>
(function($) {

    'use strict';

    // SOCIAL CLASS DEFINITION
    // ======================

    var Social = function(element, options) {
        this.$element = $(element);
        this.options = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.social.defaults, options);
        this.$day =
            this.resizeTimeout =
            this.columns =
            this.colWidth = null;
        this.init();
    }
    Social.VERSION = "1.0.0";

    Social.prototype.init = function() {
        this.$cover = this.$element.find(this.options.cover);
        this.$day = this.$element.find(this.options.day);
        this.$item = this.$element.find(this.options.item);
        this.$status = this.$element.find(this.options.status);
        this.colWidth = this.options.colWidth;

        var _this = this;

        // TODO: transition disabled for mobile (animation starts after touch end)


        // Prevent 'vh' bug on iOS7
        if($.Pages.getUserAgent() == 'mobile'){
            //var wh = $(window).height();
            this.$cover.length && this.$cover.css('height', 400);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            this.$day.length && this.$day.isotope({
                transformsEnabled: false,
                "itemSelector": this.options.item,
                "masonry": {
                    "columnWidth": this.colWidth,
                    "gutter": 20,
                    "isFitWidth": true
                }
            });
        }.bind(this), 500);

    }

    // Set container width in order to align it horizontally. 

    Social.prototype.setContainerWidth = function() {
        var currentColumns = Math.floor(($('body').width() - 100) / this.colWidth);
        if (currentColumns !== this.columns) {
            // set new column count
            this.columns = currentColumns;
            // apply width to container manually, then trigger relayout
            this.$day.length && this.$day.width(this.columns * (this.colWidth + 20));
        }
    }


    // SOCIAL PLUGIN DEFINITION
    // =======================

    function Plugin(option) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var data = $this.data('pg.social');
            var options = typeof option == 'object' && option;

            if (!data) $this.data('pg.social', (data = new Social(this, options)));
            if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]();
        })
    }

    var old = $.fn.social

    $.fn.social = Plugin
    $.fn.social.Constructor = Social

    $.fn.social.defaults = {
        cover: '[data-social="cover"]',
        day: '[data-social="day"]',
        status: '[data-social="status"]',
        item: '[data-social="item"]',
        colWidth: 300
    }

    // SOCIAL NO CONFLICT
    // ====================

    $.fn.social.noConflict = function() {
        $.fn.social = old;
        return this;
    }

    // SOCIAL DATA API
    //===================

    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('[data-pages="social"]').each(function() {
            var $social = $(this);
            $social.social($social.data());

            setTimeout(function() {
                $social.find('[data-social="status"] li.current input').focus();
            }, 1000);

        })
    })

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        $('[data-pages="social"]').each(function() {
            var $social = $(this);

            clearTimeout($social.data('pg.social').resizeTimeout);

            $social.data('pg.social').resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                // $social.data('pg.social').setContainerWidth();
                $social.data('pg.social').$day.isotope('layout');
            }, 300);

        });

    });


})(window.jQuery);
```